# Hot to get specific rows from contentProvider?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-contentprovider

I'm trying to create multiple tables by inserting a tag for each column in the table and then sort them according to the tag name

- Example:
- **tags = food**
- food-banana
- food-apple
- **tags = movies**
- movie-E.T
- movie-SpiderMan

I know how to do it in the regular method with some for loops like this example:

```
public ArrayList<Items> getall(String tag ,boolean first) {
    open();
    ArrayList<Items> list = new ArrayList<Items>();
    Cursor cur = myDb.query(TABLE_NOTES, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    while (cur.moveToNext()) {
        if (first) {
        Items data = new Items(cur.getString(1),cur.getString(2),cur.getFloat(3),cur.getString(4));
        list.add(data);
        }
        if(cur.getString(2).equals(tag)&&!first){
            Items data = new Items(cur.getString(1),cur.getString(2),cur.getFloat(3),cur.getString(4));
        list.add(data);
        }
    }
    close();
    return list;
}
```

but how can i do it with a ContentProvider?
    public class StatusProvider extends ContentProvider {

```
        public static final String AUTH = "content://com.example.mulitplytables.provider";
        public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse(AUTH);

        SQLiteDatabase db;
        DbHandler myDb;


        @Override
        public boolean onCreate() {
            myDb = new DbHandler(getContext());
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
                String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
            db = myDb.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor corsor = db.query(DbHandler.TABLE, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);
            return corsor;
        }

        @Override
        public String getType(Uri uri) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
            db = myDb.getWritableDatabase();
            long id = db.insertWithOnConflict(DbHandler.TABLE, null, values,SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);
            if(id != -1){
                uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(uri, Long.toString(id));
            }
            return uri;
        }

        @Override
        public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
            db = myDb.getWritableDatabase();
            int result  = db.delete(DbHandler.TABLE, selection, selectionArgs);
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection,
                String[] selectionArgs) {
            db = myDb.getWritableDatabase();
            int result = db.updateWithOnConflict(DbHandler.TABLE, values,selection, selectionArgs, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);
            return result;  

        }

    }
```

public class DbHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

```
    public static final String DBName = "noteDb.db";
    public static final int Version = 1;


    public static final String TABLE = "Notes";
    public static final String ID = "_id";
    public static final String NOTES = "myNotes";
    public static final String TAGS = "myTags";
    public static final String SET1 = "set1";
    public static final String SET2 = "set2";

    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_NOTES = "CREATE TABLE "
            + TABLE + "(" + ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + NOTES
            + " TEXT,"+TAGS + " TEXT,"+SET1+ " REAL,"+SET2+" TEXT)";


    public DbHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DBName, null, Version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_NOTES);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }



}
```

EDIted:

```
    static int MY_LOADER_ID = 1;
    DbHandler myDb;

    ListView lv;
    CustomCursorAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<Notes> list = new ArrayList<Notes>();
    Spinner sp;
    String[] spData;
     ArrayList<String> sortedList;
     ArrayAdapter<String> adapterSpinner;

      String category = "";
      String note = "";
      float set1 = 0;
      String set2 = ""; 
      Cursor cursor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        cursor = getContentResolver().query(StatusProvider.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        adapter = new CustomCursorAdapter(this, cursor, 0);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        getLoaderManager().initLoader(MY_LOADER_ID, null, this);

        sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        adapterSpinner = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, setSpinnerTags());
        sp.setAdapter(adapterSpinner);
        sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    }



    //Set the tags names on the spinner
    private String[] setSpinnerTags() {
        ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String tagGet = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbHandler.TAGS));
            if(!result.contains(tagGet)){
                result.add(tagGet);
            }
        }
        spData = new String[result.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
            spData[i] = result.get(i);
        }
        return spData;
    }



    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {

//HERE is the title of th tags 
        String theTitle = spData[position];

        //?????? What i do need the write here?

            switch (position) {
            case 0:

                break;

            default:
                break;
            }
    }


    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    }



    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        return new CursorLoader(this, StatusProvider.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        adapter.swapCursor(data);

    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        adapter.swapCursor(null);

    }
    public void refreshList(){
        getLoaderManager().restartLoader(MY_LOADER_ID, null, this);
    }

}
```

Comment: see selection and selectionArgs params

Comment: Im a little bit new with content provider. can you give me example please?

Comment: it has little to do with content provider, i meant params to db.query

Comment: I cant understand you.. (

Comment: create a selection where second column = tag

Comment: ok, but how? and where to start?

Comment: what is your db schema? run sqlite3 your.db and type .schema

Comment: I added to my question above the Dbhandler

Comment: String selection = "myTags = ?"; String[] selectionArgs = {tag};

Comment: Sorry to bother you .It's work onley if i hard coded it. but in my app i have Spinner with the Tags and how can i change the query when spinner item selected? see above :)

Comment: @G.BlakeMeike what !?!?

Comment: @G.BlakeMeike prize & money isn't everything ;-)

Comment: @pskink You helped me a lot and I appreciate it. the second question is the last for to day ;)